# Covariance matrix of linear transformation of eigenvector matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $K_t=E'R_t$ where $E$ is a matrix with the eigenvectors of the covariance matrix of $R_t$.

According to my book, then the following holds:
$Var(K_t)=Var(E'R_t)=E'Var(R_t)E=E'VE\overset{\text{why?}}{=}E'E\Lambda=\Lambda$

I don't understand the first to last equality (I understand the last equality). Could someone please explain to me why that holds?

Answer (score 0):

What  did you try?  You could use the well-known formula
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\Var}{Var}   
    \Var(AX) = A \Var(X) A^T
$$
You can find such formulas here:   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_random_variable